# How to use the Page Object Pattern in Play 2.1 test classes?

Tags: playframework-2.0, fluent

I am a new user of Play and working through the ToDo List example (the beginner Java-based tutorial).

I am now experimenting with adding test cases using the Page Object Pattern (https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium#page-object-pattern).

Unfortunately, my initial attempts to implement this pattern have not gone well.   My entire system is available at GitHub if you would like to quickly download and play with it.  Here is a link to my test class, which shows both a running test case (that does not use the Page Object Pattern) and a failing test case that attempts to use the Page Object Pattern:

https://github.com/philipmjohnson/playexample1/blob/master/test/IntegrationTest.java

Here is the error when I run the test cases inside the Play console):

```
[error] Test IntegrationTest.testWithPage failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:426)
[error]     at IntegrationTest.testWithPage(IntegrationTest.java:34)
[error]     ...
[error] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[error]     at org.fluentlenium.core.Fluent.goTo(Fluent.java:223)
[error]     at org.fluentlenium.core.FluentPage.go(FluentPage.java:55)
[error]     at org.fluentlenium.core.Fluent.goTo(Fluent.java:204)
[error]     at IntegrationTest$2.invoke(IntegrationTest.java:37)
[error]     at IntegrationTest$2.invoke(IntegrationTest.java:34)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:424)
```

How do I correctly implement the Page Object design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some details there :

You have to construct the page and giving it the webdriver, the page need it to manipulate the browser.

```
public ToDoListPage(WebDriver webDriver) {
    super(webDriver);
}
```

And in your test :

```
ToDoListPage todopage = new ToDoListPage(browser.getDriver());
```

Also, doesn't need to have a @Test annotation in your TodoListPage

See the pull request : [Fix](https://github.com/MathildeLemee/playexample1/commit/cb440bf357546ca573ce39529cd5b1ddeb5c07bc)